# zsh tab completion on empty line

Tags: shell, configuration, zsh

I'd like a tcsh'ism that I haven't been able to find:  On a blank line with no content, I want to press the tab key and see the equivalent of an ls.  That is to say I want

```
$ <tab>
```

to do something other then giving me a \t.  I've found fantastic resources for command completion, but not for this base case.  Any help on this would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
# expand-or-complete-or-list-files
function expand-or-complete-or-list-files() {
    if [[ $#BUFFER == 0 ]]; then
        BUFFER="ls "
        CURSOR=3
        zle list-choices
        zle backward-kill-word
    else
        zle expand-or-complete
    fi
}
zle -N expand-or-complete-or-list-files
# bind to tab
bindkey '^I' expand-or-complete-or-list-files
```

Comment: Very neat. Would it be possible to somehow hide the listing again? Tab-to-show then tab-to-hide would be nice.

Comment: Thanks John, I found your solution and adapted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729851/zsh-first-tab-completion-with-autocd

Answer (score 12):

The behavior of <kbd>Tab</kbd> at the beginning of a line is controlled by the [`insert-tab`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-insert_002dtab_002c-completion-style) [style](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-completion-system_002c-styles). However, there are only two supported behaviors:

- completion as usual, under `zstyle ':completion:*' insert-tab false`
- insert a tab, under `zstyle ':completion:*' insert-tab true`
- either one or the other under `zstyle ':completion:*' insert-tab pending[=N]`

If you just want to complete commands in that position, `zstyle ':completion:*' insert-tab true` will do. If you want something different, like listing the files in the current directory, you'll need to modify `_main_complete`.

A [recent thread on the zsh-workers list](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2011/msg00751.html) discussed `insert-tab`.

Comment: fantastic! By _main_complete it looks like you are referencing somewhere in the C code?  I'm sorry for the dumb question, but where would that be found?

Comment: @user535759: No, `_main_complete` is part of the zsh code that implements completion. It's in `Completion/Base/Core/_main_complete` in the source tree, typically installed in a location like `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Base/_main_complete`.

Comment: @llua Changing the style associated to `-command-` does not cause <Tab> to list the files in the current directory. All you've done is to *restrict* the matches to omit command names. But only things that would be completed in this position are listed, so not files in the current directory (only directories and executables depending on `autocd` and `PATH`).

Answer (score 3):

Here is complete implementation of tcsh's autolist in zsh,
when you press tab on empty line

```
% <TAB>
```

Here it is:

```
# list dir with TAB, when there are only spaces/no text before cursor,
# or complete words, that are before cursor only (like in tcsh)
tcsh_autolist() { if [[ -z ${LBUFFER// } ]]
    then BUFFER="ls " CURSOR=3 zle list-choices
    else zle expand-or-complete-prefix; fi }
zle -N tcsh_autolist
bindkey '^I' tcsh_autolist
```

If you want to emulate tcsh more closely, also add this to your .zshrc:

```
unsetopt always_last_prompt       # print completion suggestions above prompt
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote [this](https://ownyourbits.com/2017/01/30/list-files-without-stopping-to-type-in-zsh/) zsh widget that enhances the use of TAB, not only on an empty line, but also while you are typing a command.

- It will list **files** on  on an empty command line, and in the middle of any command.
- It will list **directories** on  on an empty command line.
- It will list **executables** on  on an empty command line.

It can be configured to prepend "cd " or "./" in those cases with a global variable.

`export TAB_LIST_FILES_PREFIX`

[image: tab_list_files_example]

```
# List files in zsh with <TAB>
#
# Copyleft 2017 by Ignacio Nunez Hernanz <nacho _a_t_ ownyourbits _d_o_t_ com>
# GPL licensed (see end of file) * Use at your own risk!
#
# Usage:
#   In the middle of the command line:
#     (command being typed)<TAB>(resume typing)
#
#   At the beginning of the command line:
#     <SPACE><TAB>
#     <SPACE><SPACE><TAB>
#
# Notes:
#   This does not affect other completions
#   If you want 'cd ' or './' to be prepended, write in your .zshrc 'export TAB_LIST_FILES_PREFIX'
#   I recommend to complement this with push-line-or edit (bindkey '^q' push-line-or-edit)
function tab_list_files
{
  if [[ $#BUFFER == 0 ]]; then
    BUFFER="ls "
    CURSOR=3
    zle list-choices
    zle backward-kill-word
  elif [[ $BUFFER =~ ^[[:space:]][[:space:]].*$ ]]; then
    BUFFER="./"
    CURSOR=2
    zle list-choices
    [ -z ${TAB_LIST_FILES_PREFIX+x} ] && BUFFER="  " CURSOR=2
  elif [[ $BUFFER =~ ^[[:space:]]*$ ]]; then
    BUFFER="cd "
    CURSOR=3
    zle list-choices
    [ -z ${TAB_LIST_FILES_PREFIX+x} ] && BUFFER=" " CURSOR=1
  else
    BUFFER_=$BUFFER
    CURSOR_=$CURSOR
    zle expand-or-complete || zle expand-or-complete || {
      BUFFER="ls "
      CURSOR=3
      zle list-choices
      BUFFER=$BUFFER_
      CURSOR=$CURSOR_
    }
  fi
}
zle -N tab_list_files
bindkey '^I' tab_list_files

# uncomment the following line to prefix 'cd ' and './' 
# when listing dirs and executables respectively
#export TAB_LIST_FILES_PREFIX

# these two lines are usually included by oh-my-zsh, but just in case
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit

# uncomment the following line to complement tab_list_files with ^q
#bindkey '^q' push-line-or-edit

# License
#
# This script is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
# under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This script is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this script; if not, write to the
# Free Software Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330,
# Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
```